# What does “after you” mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I came across this sentence in a conversation book. It is by itself alone, so It doesn’t have context around it. The sentence is *”Please clean up the room **after you**.”*

I think it could mean *after you’ve done with the room* **or** *behind you*.

Answer (score 2):

I can see why this would be tricky for a learner to parse. The key is knowing that ***clean up after*** is a phrasal verb.

Cambridge defines it as:

> **[clean up after sb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/clean-up-after-sb)** `phrasal verb` to remove dirt or problems that someone has made : *I'm fed up with cleaning up after you all the time*.

Macmillan says:

> [**clean up after someone**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/clean-up-after) `phrasal verb` to clean a place after someone has made it dirty or messy : *Residents have been told to clean up after their dogs*.

and M-W says:

> **[clean up after](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clean%20up%20after)** `idiom` to make a place clean after it has been left dirty or messy by (someone) : *His mother is always cleaning up after him. You should learn to clean up after yourself*.

As for the sentence in the book, I think I would word it slightly differently:

> *Please clean up the room after **yourself***.

That’s how I’ve usually heard the phrase used reflexively, when “you” has made the mess and “you” is expected to clean it.

Comment: Aw! I completely missed it! Thanks! This is indeed new to me...clean up after someone is *a phrasal verb!* :)